# How can I get tags for all tapes in AWS Storage Gateway?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-storage-gateway

In the past you used to be able to view tags for tapes in the AWS Storage gateway on the web console, but it seems AWS has removed that option now. The only way to view tags is to individually select each tape and click on the tags tab.

I have over 100 tapes and doing this manually would be rather time consuming. Is there a command I can output a list of every tape barcode and it's associated tag?

Alternatively, we only use about 10 or so tags across all these tapes (one tag per tape) and I've tried using a Python/boto3 script (I'm not python guru though) to output all the tapes of a particular tag, sadly the below script isn't working entirely. It will output some tapes but not everything. Example if I search for the tag "Warehouse" it will return about 8 tapes - which didn't sound right. So looking manually in the AWS console I've already manually found 3-4 tapes with this tag and was NOT returned in the list using this code:

```
#Import the boto3 library
import boto3
 
#Create the tape gateway client
tgw_client = boto3.client('storagegateway')
 
#Create a list of the tapes
tapes = tgw_client.list_tapes()['TapeInfos']
 
#Create a for loop to process each tape in the tapes list
for tape in tapes:
    #Set the TapeARN variable
    tape_arn = tape['TapeARN']
    #Describe the tags for the tape using the tape ARN
    tape_tag = tgw_client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceARN = tape_arn)
    #Exception handing
    try:
        #Check to see if the first tag value matches job001
        if tape_tag['Tags'][0]['Value'] == 'Warehouse':
            #If the tag value matches job001, then print the list_tags_for_resource response for that tape
            print(tape_tag)
        #Ignore tapes which do not have the job001 tag
        else:
            pass
    except:
        pass
```

Any help in getting an output of tapes and tags or how to fix this python script would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Your script looks pretty good, two things that might help:

1. Are there multiple tags per tape instance? If so, you will want to loop through the tape_tag (appears you are only pulling the first tag in the array)
2. In your IF statement you are matching on the string - might be helpful to use the .lower() method to make the comparison case insensitive

Comment: Hey Tyler! To answer your questions:
1. Yes each tape only has one tag assigned to it.
2. The tags are assigned via Veeam and I've exported each tag name exactly as typed in Veeam. For instance, using the above script to search for "Exchange" returns no results, yet I'm looking at one tape right now in the console with that tag. Nonetheless how would I add .lower into this code?

Comment: Thanks for the additional context, helpful that each tape instance only has one tag. The lowercase comparison may help filter the results since your operator is looking for the exact result (case sensitive).. to do that, you would want to add something like this..... if tape_tag['Tags'][0]['Value'].lower() == 'warehouse':

Comment: Also, one more suggestion - do you know how many tape instances you have in your account? By default, the listTapes operation returns a maximum of up to 100 tapes. If the number of tapes returned in the response is truncated, the response includes a Marker element that you can use in your subsequent request to retrieve the next set of tapes. You would need to pull the next page(s) to make a complete run through all the tape instances you have in the account.

Comment: Our storage gateway shows exactly 206 tapes at the moment. Any idea how I could update the script to continue searching all the tapes?

Comment: If you have 206 tapes that's more than likely why you see partial results in your script output. Look at the full response, which should include a Marker element that you can use in subsequent requests to retrieve the next set of tapes. Here is boto3 doc for reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/storagegateway.html#StorageGateway.Client.list_tapes

Answer (score 1):

The script is not returning all of the results because the account has 206 tape instances, and the list_tapes method returns a max of 100 by default. To handle this and pull the complete list, we need to the evaluate the list_tapes response and use the Marker element to make a subsequent request to retrieve the next set(s) of tapes.

Below is a reference script for listing all Lambda functions that can be easily updated to pull the tape instances from Storage Gateway. Just update the client and response mapping, and then add your own logic for evaluating.

```
import boto3
    
def list_functions(marker):
    try:
        client = boto3.client('lambda')
        if marker is not None:
            print("Retrieving next page...")
            response = client.list_functions(
            Marker=marker,
            )
        else:
            print("Retrieving first page..")
            response = client.list_functions(
            )
        return response
    except Exception as e: print(e)

def runtime():
    try:
        flist = []
        marker = None
        data = list_functions(marker)
        if 'NextMarker' in data:
            marker = data['NextMarker']
        else:
            marker = None
        for i in data['Functions']:
            flist.append(i['FunctionName'])
        
        while marker is not None:
            if '==' in marker:
                data = list_functions(marker)
                if 'NextMarker' in data:
                    marker = data['NextMarker']
                else:
                    marker = None

                for i in data['Functions']:
                    flist.append(i['FunctionName'])
            else:
                marker = None

        print(flist)
    except Exception as e: print(e)

runtime()
```

Boto3 documentation for reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/storagegateway.html#StorageGateway.Client.list_tapes